# PHP MySql - How to prioritize a process

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little more than hundred php scripts running on my server right now. Each one of them run loops and insert data into my db. I did that in order to learn killing processes in mysql. So to kill them, I coded a php file that loops through the processlist and kill them one by one. The problem is that this script is not executed. It keeps loading in my browser (no errors...). Also do note that I can't manually launch a show processlist in mysql, as mysql is totally overloaded at the moment, and nothing is responding. So what I guess is that my 'killing process' script is the last one on the queue and will only be executed at the end. So my question is to know if there is a way to force a process in mysql and put it at priority number one. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc

This is how I am killing the processes:

```
$qry = mysql_query("SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
  $process_id=$row["Id"];
    $sql="KILL $process_id";
    mysql_query($sql);

}
```

Comment: i think this is server job related question . Tell me how you are Killining :-)

Comment: Hello zod. I just edited the post...

Comment: Do killing needs privilege !  better scripts are there.. try to print also  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html

Comment: Is it MyISAM? There's [HIGH_PRIORITY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html), [LOW_PRIORITY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html), and [--low-priority-updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html) for MyISAM.

Comment: Hi Marcus. No it is InnoDB...

Comment: @zod I am running MAMP. I do all the connections with the default root   user and password. If I create a user for all the queries, and use the root for the killing processes, do you think it will resolve the problem?

Comment: I'm almost certain that you cannot send a KILL query via `mysql_query` (trying to find a source to cite right now). Also, please stop using the `mysql_*` library of functions and use either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Hello Brian. I read on many post that people use mysql_query to execute a KILL query. Also on the mySql site...

Comment: Here some news: I created a user account that has all the rights except the SUPER one. So I launch my queries with the user account and the 'kill script' with the root account. The kill script works fine if I launch just one or two queries. But when running a little more than hundred, the kill script is not executed. It is 'loading'. Hope someone can help me understand this and help me find a solution...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will actually affect MySQL, but on Unix/Linux, you could try calling [`proc_nice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-nice.php) near the top of your script with a negative increment (like -20). It basically does the same thing as the [`nice` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nice).

From the [Wikipedia page on `nice`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29):

> "... nice is used to invoke a utility or shell script with a particular priority, thus giving the process more or less CPU time than other processes. A niceness of −20 is the highest priority and 19 or 20 is the lowest priority. The default niceness for processes is inherited from its parent process, usually 0."

Comment: There's a similar command called [`pcntl_setpriority()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-setpriority.php) that lets you to set the priority of any process.